# Why does my Wemos D1 Mini stops working while charging via solar?

Tags: esp8266, solar

I'm using an battery shield to recharge my battery. I want to use a solar panel, so I bought one (5V 240mA). I'm pretty sure, it won't recharge my battery fully, but that's not the point.
I've assembled my board with my shield, soldered the solar panel together with an schottky-diode and put it on USB (since the shield allows charging via USB). All fine, I get some electric power in the sun - yeah!

But my Wemos D1 Mini only runs for say 2-3 minutes and than ... dead? Restarting works, but only lasts again 2-3 minutes. This only happens while the battery shield is charging via solar. I already tested using any USB charging (my computer) - this simply works.

Basically I rebuild the circuit like described on [TheAustrian/Wemos-D1-Mini-BME280-Weather-Station](https://github.com/TheAustrian/Wemos-D1-Mini-BME280-Weather-Station) but only one solar panel attached and using the Wemos D1 Mini Battery Shield instead of the TP4056.

Any hints what's going on? Why can't I run the board while charging via solar? Did I miss something?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the solar panel needs to be big enough to both charge the battery *and* run the Wemos D1 at the same time. Lack of current will cause bad things to happen.

Comment: @Majenko how can I be sure? What specs do I need to read? :-D

Answer (score 1):

The TP4056 Module will output a max of 4.2V which is less than the 5V the Wemos D1 Mini is expecting on its 5V connection (Assuming you have connected the circuit as shown in the Github guide). When the solar panel is charging it's likely that the TP4056 is causing a driving issue on the supply of the Wemos causing it to potentially [Brownout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownout_(electricity)) .

I would not connect the solar panel to the Wemos like this, I would have it connected to the battery then the battery connected to a 5V Step Up Power Converter like shown below (This reduces efficiency but give the MCU a stable supply),

[image]

My recommendation for the wiring,

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but as far as I can see, this the Wemos D1 battery shield does provide a [boost converter](https://docs.wemos.cc/en/latest/d1_mini_shiled/battery.html) (step-up converter?). But I also just noticed: it states 0.5A _or_ max. 1A charging current. Maybe my problems lies in using _one_ solar providing 0.25A?

Comment: As I stated in my question: I'm using the Wemos D1 battery shield *instead* the TP4056.

Comment: Sorry I should have re-read you question, okay so the module is getting 5V which is good. The symptoms still sound like the Wemos is browning out. It's very possible the solar panel is not generating enough current to power the regulator (You could get a multi-meter on the output to see what's going on under load). Is the battery completely drained, do you have a way to fully charge it and repeat the test? In theory the solar panel should only be charging the battery not directly driving the 5V regulator.

Comment: Yes I do have one. I'm new to electronics, so: where do I need to measure output? On the solar panel or output of the shield (a.k.a input of Wemos)? V or A?

Comment: I would measure the voltage cross the 5V connection on the Wemos module (So Wemos 5V to GND). Keep measuring it while the Wemos run & see if it changes when the Wemos crashes (The voltage will likely drop < 5V then potentially jump back up to 5V once the crash has occured and the current load has dropped). If the 5V supply is stable during the crash you may need to switch to measuring current (Amps A). So in line 5V as shown here - https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/test-methods/meters/how-to-measure-current.php